# Conflict "add-migration" and "update-database" result for entity framework code base migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to run code base entity framework migration.  And I always get this error (except the initial migration) when run "add-migration" command: Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201607141552034_Add_storeId_firstname_to_customer]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.  However, if I try to run "update-database -Verbose -ConnectionStringName "ZzaDbConnectionString", I get an very confusing/conflict error:  No pending explicit migrations.  I tried to delete the migration file then use add-migration to create it again.  It only work once.  The next time (for example, if I want to add a column to my table), I got the same error.  Any suggestion why the problem?  Thanks.

EDIT: add code and configuration.

This is Entity class.

```
namespace Zza.Entities
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is Context class:

```
namespace Zza.Data
{
    public class ZzaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is console class:

```
namespace TestEFMigration
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateDataBase();
        }

        private static void CreateDataBase()
        {
            var context = new ZzaDbContext();

            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

context class's app.config

```
<add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite‌​;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Console's app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

iceheart

Comment: After you apply the migration check the database table __MigrationHistory. There should be a record in there that EF checks to see if it has been applied. Examine the ContextKey column and make sure it matches the context where your migrations exist.

Comment: From _MigrationHistory table, ContextKey is Zza.Data.Migrations.Configuration.  This is the configuration class which inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration<Zza.Data.ZzaDbContext> so I suppose the context is Zza.Data.ZzaDbContext?

Comment: How are your projects and connection strings structured? I see you are using  -ConnectionStringName "ZzaDbConnectionString". If you set the connection string in the context constructor you shouldn't need to do that. Your issue could be related to that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Steve:  Thanks for reply.  I edited my original post with code and configurations.  Thanks.

Comment: Add the constructor public ZzaDbContext ()  : base("ZzaDbConnectionString") {} to your ZzaDbContext class. Then I would reset migrations by deleting the __MigrationHistory table from the database and the Migrations folder from the project. Then in Package Manager console make sure context project is selected, enable-migration, add-migration Initial, update-database.